# Question Regarding Bases of Vector Spaces and Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If you find a basis for a vector space $V$ is that basis automatically a basis for any subspace of $V$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it what you really mean to ask is:

> If $B$ is a basis for a vector space $V$ then is some subset of $B$ a basis for an arbitrary subspace of $V$?

No. Take the usual basis $\{ (1,0), (0,1) \}$ for $\mathbb R^2$ and then consider the subspace $W = \{ \lambda(1,1) \ : \ \lambda \in \mathbb R \}$.

Not only is no subset of the usual basis a basis for $W$, but neither basis vector is even a member of $W$.

Comment: Furthermore, a basis for $V$ is *never* a basis for a subspace of $V$ other than $V$ itself.

Comment: Note that what *is* true is that $W$ is contained in the span of the original basis, although of course that's both trivial and not what the OP is asking.